# Calculate complex number considering...

Tags: complex-numbers

How can I calculate:

$$
\frac{1-Z}{1+Z}
$$

...considering $Z = \cos(\alpha) + i \sin (\alpha)$

I have replaced the expression but I don't know how can I continue...

Comment: So the number $\;z\;$ is on the unit circle in the complex plane?

Comment: I only have the information which I have put, I am newbie, sorry

Comment: Hint: $u \bar{u} = |u|^2$, where $\bar{u}$ is the complex conjugate of $u$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As given, $\;|z|=1\;$ ,so

$$\frac{1-z}{1+z}\cdot\frac{1+\overline z}{1+\overline z}=\frac{1+\overline z-z-|z|^2}{|1+z|^2}=-\frac{2\;\text{Im}\,z}{|1+z|^2}i$$

And since

$$|1+z|^2=|1+\cos x+i\sin x|^2=1+2\cos x+\cos^2x+\sin^2x=2(1+\cos x)\;,\;\;\text{Im}\,z=\sin x$$

we get

$$-\frac{2\sin x}{2(1+\cos x)}i=-\frac{\sin x}{2\left(1-\sin^2\frac x2\right)}i$$

The last identity just in case you want an expression with thesame trigonometric function. tThe denominator can be changed to $\;2\cos^2\frac x2\;$ , of course.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand why in the first part, second step: $1 + \overline z - z - |z|^2$ is equal to $-2*Im(z)*i$, because $\overline z - z$ is equal to $2*Im(z)*i$, what happen with $1 - |z|^2$ ? is it equal to -1?

Comment: @AlbertoFernández , $\;|z|=1\implies |z|^2=1\iff 1-|z|^2=0\;$

Comment: and why do you suppose that $|z| = 1$ ? is it necessary? can I give it another value?

Comment: It's not "suppose", @AlbertoFernández: you wrote that $\;z=\cos x+i\sin x\;$ , and this means, as you can easily check, that $\;|z|=1\;$  !

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. So if I easily replace the equation get |z| = 1, but I have a doubt, when I make this change, what happen with the $i$ (imaginary unit) which is in the equation? Thanks!

Comment: What "change" did you mean, @AlbertoFernández ? I don't understand.

Comment: I have already undertood it, newbie fail... The last problem for me is this: $|1+\cos x+i\sin x|^2=1+2\cos x+\cos^2x+\sin^2x$ I don't understand how do you get that result. Sorry, for this type of question. Thank you

Comment: is it related with Moivre's formula?

Comment: No, it is the definition of module of complex numbers: $$|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\;,\;\;a,b\in\Bbb R$$

Comment: Ah ok, it's very easy now :P. Thank you very much again